# pass terminal output to GUI using wxpython

Tags: python, redirect, python-2.7, wxpython

Hi  all i am using python 2.7 and for GUI wxpython, in linux environment. I wants to redirect output from terminal to Message box, how it will happen?
My code is:

```
 p = subprocess.call(" grep "Wanted" .filename | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c11-20", shell=True)
```

This will give proper output in terminal,but when i call it in message box it shows "0".

```
 wx.MessageBox(" file name:'%s' % (str(p)), "info")
```

how to print those which are displayed in terminal , i am newbie to python world and have less knowledge in python. Searched for answer but couldn't any answer.so dropping here for solution and guidance.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be prefered/simpler to use Popen (But I rarly use subprocess.call so I do no know). But you example should work fine (with the mentioned fix from Ashwini Chaudhary), from what I see.

```
import subprocess
import wx

def main():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    text = p.stdout.readlines()
    text = "".join(text)

    wx.MessageBox("file names:\n%s" % text, "info")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    main()
```

Anyways: Any reason to involve Bash, cant python do the same?

Comment: have little knowledge in bash so.

Comment: That depends, I'm not a 100% sure what you're achiving with your bash-line. I can assit you if you elaborate what you are achiving with that gerp-command.